# Need help in MongoDB: Update an element without specifying its position

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a document in a collection as follows:

```
db.persons.insert ( {
    name: {first: 'Nancy', last: 'Karin'},
    gender: 'F',
    yearOfBirth: 1992,
    livesIn: 'Montreal',
    countriesVisited: ['Canada', 'United States of America'],
    languages: [
        {name: 'English', proficiency: 'Fluent'},
        {name: 'French', proficiency: 'Fluent'},
        {name: 'German', proficiency: 'Intermediate'},
        {name: 'Greek', proficiency: 'Intermediate'},
        {name: 'Latin', proficiency: 'Intermediate'},
        {name: 'Sanskrit', proficiency: 'Beginner'} ]
} )
```

The following command is giving an error:

```
db.persons.update (
    {'name.first': 'Nancy', 'name.last': 'Karin', 'languages.name': 'German'},
    {$set: {'languages.?.name': 'Italian'} }
)
```

The error message that I get is:

```
can't append to array using string field name: ?
```

I can't see what mistake I am making. The above command seems to be in accordance with MongoDB 2.4.0 documentation, page 185, "Update an element without specifying its position".

Thanks for your help.

Pradyumn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `?` by `$` according to [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update).

Answer (score 1):

```
db.persons.update (
    {'name.first': 'Nancy', 'name.last': 'Karin', 'languages.name': 'German'},
    {$set: {'languages.$.name': 'Italian'} }
```

if we don`t know the index of the array where we have to put data for modification of existing data.. then we need to use $ on behalf of index number .. I guess its clear now

Answer (score 0):

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("583d79f8f6b2a2937a9da48a"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-11-29T12:52:08.089Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-11-29T12:52:08.089Z"),
"deletedAt" : null,
"deleted" : false,
"user_id" : ObjectId("57eb939b8a1e7c6e2ea3ab21"),
"event_id" : ObjectId("57eb939b8a1e7c6e2ea3ab22"),
"order_id" : "WQArcsdcg cgf",
"amount" : 200,
"status" : "ordered",
"attachment" : [ 
    "WQArcsdcg cgf/ACL REPORT.xls", 
    "WQArcsdcg cgf/woohoo.jpg"
],
"Date" : ISODate("2016-11-30T07:40:36.482Z"),
"__v" : 0
```

### }

```
domain.GiftCard.update(
            {
            event_id:id,
            'attachment.0':"WQArcsdcg cgf/ACL REPORT.xls",

        },{
            $set:{'attachment.$': "Tested By Shashwat"}

        } 
            ,function(err, res)
        {


        callback(null , res)

        })
```

Result will be

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("583d79f8f6b2a2937a9da48a"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-11-29T12:52:08.089Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-11-29T12:52:08.089Z"),
"deletedAt" : null,
"deleted" : false,
"user_id" : ObjectId("57eb939b8a1e7c6e2ea3ab21"),
"event_id" : ObjectId("57eb939b8a1e7c6e2ea3ab22"),
"order_id" : "WQArcsdcg cgf",
"amount" : 200,
"status" : "ordered",
"attachment" : [ 
    "Tested By Shashwat", 
    "WQArcsdcg cgf/woohoo.jpg"
],
"Date" : ISODate("2016-11-30T07:40:36.482Z"),
"__v" : 0
```

}